# TChromium не корректно выводит содержимое сайта

Tags: delphi, tchromium

Добрых суток!

В своем проекте использую компонент TChromium, компонент взял с https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3, в проекте использую libcef.dll версии 3.2924.1570.0. К сожалению на не которых сайтах появились артефакты при выводе содержимого страницы... [image: TChromium - не корректный вывод содержимого сайта]

Кто знает как это можно вылечить ? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в размере минимального шрифта указанного для браузера. Лечиться такой командой:

```
Browser.FontOptions.MinimumFontSize := 14;
```